# jquery (null is null or not an object) error on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I load jquery using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it works on IE9, firefox, chrome, safari but not IE8. I tried the developer/debugger tools but still don't understand why this is an issue.

This is the character code jquery supposedly has error on: 32039. 
On that line there is such function:

```
G=function(a){
   var b=F.exec(a);
   b&&(b[1]=(b[1]||"").toLowerCase(),b[3]=b[3]&&new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)"+b[3]+"(?:\\s|$)"));
   return b
}
```

Anyone came across this issue as well?

The site is http://www.kanersan.com

I am not calling jquery before it is loaded and I'm loading it inside the head tag.

Comment: where are you including it? Are you calling anything for jquery before jquery is loaded? Do you have a link?

Comment: Did you intend the line to look like that? Those aren't valid tags as you've typed them...

Comment: I like the error "null is null". Says it all, really.

Comment: Works fine for me in all IE states 6+

Comment: Should load fine - there must be another issue. What's the rest of your code?

Comment: Have you tried the non-minified version? End the `src` with `/1.7.1/jquery.js"` instead of `/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"`.

Comment: An error like this is usually caused by something else (e.g. referencing a non-existent object, or including jQuery twice). What else is going on on your page?

Comment: Could it be because I'm trying to access a div that doesn't exist?

Comment: Okay, I tried including the regular version instead of .min and still no luck. However, I removed a jquery call trying to get a div which didn't actually exist in the index (header actually) page and the error disappeared from that page. It still remains in the blog.php though. So I'm guessing there is a similar jquery call that is not finding a div it is trying to access. It's funny the other browsers handle this well!

Comment: I believe it's because IE8 javascript throws an error if jquery tries to access a non-existing element (such as a div). I'll debug and post my results here. Thanks for help everyone!

Comment: I doubt that accessing a non-existent element with jQuery typically throws an error, even in IE8; it will just return an empty array in most cases

Comment: What else are you using besides plain jQuery?

Comment: How exactly do you use this function? Here is a fiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/mmeah/hKKBH/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in jQuery 1.7.1 when used with SyntaxHighlighter

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10961

So you have to upgrade jQuery to 1.7.2 and everything will be working fine.

Comment: I updated jquery to 1.7.2 but I don't have that old computer which was running ie8. So I tried http://netrenderer.com/ to render the site in ie8 but I'm not sure if the error still shows up. It looks like it doesn't from the screenshot. Any idea how to test it? I have IE9 on my computer and I don't think there is any way to go back.

Comment: If you press F12 when running IE9 you will get the developer tools. There you can change the browser mode and document mode to IE8 or IE7 standards

Comment: @c0d3Junk13: download and install IETester http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 3):

try to folow some steps:-

1.jQuery is not being loaded, this is not likely specific to IE8. Check the path on your jQuery include. statement. Or better yet,.. TRy to give direct path.

2.May be because of compatibility issue.. Try to give compatibility solutions..
Things worked in IE6, Firefox, and IE8 running in IE7 compatibility mode; but not in 'normal' IE8. My solution was to put this code in the header

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

As to why jquery isn't working in IE8 I'm unclear.

3.Try to load your jquery on window load.

4.Try to define your jquery file in top..

5.Very important point - try to check your html and jquery code.. IE is very sensetive for code.. so cross check your Html code ,... Is everything is fine..

6.Changing browser sercurity level to allow executing external javascript code.

7.Replicate javascript framwork..

May this will help You !!!!!!!!1

Answer (score -3):

Some things worth trying...

- Remove `type="text/javascript"` like so: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
- Make sure you reference `jquery.min.js` **before** your javascript code that uses jQuery.

Most probably, the above suggestions will not help, but since the problem sounds IE8 specific, I believe it's worth a try doing some trivial things that might solve the problem.

Comment: You're correct that your suggestions do not help. Yes, the type declaration is optional in html5, but including it won't break anything. And if the problem were the order the scripts were loaded, he would be getting very different errors.